# How large should the recv buffer for web crawler to download web page in read()?

Tags: c++, sockets, http, buffer, httprequest

I'm writing a web crawler in C++ and want to figure out the best approach to read the response of a http request.

Currently I'm using a buffer of 1M size to contain the recv message in read() (count is 4K bytes for read()). This is the max size of webpage I would like to crawl. However this is sort of waste so I'm also thinking about other approaches as below:

1. Send http HEAD request in the first round and read the content-length info from header. Create a char array with size of content-length and send http GET then to retrieve the content.
   **Q1:** What if the header info from server does not have content-lenght?
   **Q2:** This approach doubles the network traffic. Is it worthy paying such overhead?
2. Send http GET directly and using a smaller buffer (e.g. 16K bytes). But not processing the response until all data is received, instead processing the data once the buffer is full and then clean the buffer to receive the rest.
   **Q1:** In this way the crawler may need a few iterations to read a large webpage completely. If the processing job is time-costly and multiple webpages are being read at the same time,  could the waiting data from network exceeds system buffer and cause packet loss?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Currently I'm using a buffer of 1M size to contain the recv message in read() (count is 4K bytes for read()). This is the max size of webpage I would like to crawl. However this is sort of waste

It certainly is. You won't read more than a couple of K per read operation anyway, so a huge buffer is pointless.

> Send http HEAD request in the first round and read the content-length info from header. Create a char array with size of content-length and send http GET then to retrieve the content.

That's another network operation. Also wasteful.

> Q1: What if the header info from server does not have content-length?

Not sure that's valid for HEAD, but you would have to check the RFC.

> Q2: This approach doubles the network traffic.

No it doesn't. It doubles the number of request/response pairs. It's not the same thing.

> Is it worthy paying such overhead?

No.

> Send http GET directly and using a smaller buffer (e.g. 16K bytes).

Definitely.

> But not processing the response until all data is received

Why not? Why not process it as you receive it? That's the best approach of all. Smallest buffer, lowest latency.

> instead processing the data once the buffer is full and then clean the buffer to receive the rest.

You never need to clean a buffer.

> Q1: In this way the crawler may need a few iterations to read a large webpage completely

You always need iterations to read a Web page or anything else from a network. The recv() function is only guaranteed to transfer at least one byte in blocking model unless EOS or a error occurs. It's not obliged to fill the buffer, and it can't unless your socket receive buffer is also 1M and you've wasted enough time between reads that it has filled. If you program properly this won't happen.

> If the processing job is time-costly and multiple webpages are being read at the same time, could the waiting data from network exceeds system buffer and cause packet loss?

Not in TCP. It will just cause the sender to stall and waste time.

Comment: Hi EJP thanks for the detailed answer. Two more questions:1. You mentioned "Why not process it as you receive it?", what does "process" mean here? It is storing the buffer into a separate container for later analyzing/parsing work, or the analyzing work itself? 2. The solution I got to reduce the buffer size is: Copy buffer of read() into a flexible container (e.g. std::string) in every loop, and analyze on the container after all data is read from the server. Is this idea in the correct direction or there are other better paradigms? Thank you.

Comment: (1) The analyzing work itself. (2) see (1). You don't need the end of the data to start parsing the beginning of the data. A compiler, for example, or a XML or HTML parser, could be fed a byte at a time of a source text, a byte per minute, and it would still be perfectly happy. So should your code.